# Deleted answers for 10.000 + users

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

So for some high traffic questions there are a lot of deleted answers taking up space like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), page after page of deleted answers.

Could we have some option to ignore the deleted answers?

Comment: Since the duplicate doesn't answer the question directly, but rather, indirectly through another question (on meta.SE) in the comments, look at this [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132134/hide-deleted-answer-content) for a probable solution.